# adding row manualy into DataGrid using VB6

Tags: vb6

i want to display the data into DataGrid manually in VB6, source of data is not from database or other source. I have created the column, like this:

```
For i = 2 To 4
    DataGrid1.Columns.Add i
Next i

DataGrid1.Columns(0).Caption = "No"
DataGrid1.Columns(1).Caption = "Subdataset"
DataGrid1.Columns(2).Caption = "Dimension"
DataGrid1.Columns(3).Caption = "Check"
DataGrid1.Columns(3).Caption = "Detail"
```

but i can't add row and add value into it, i have tried like this:

Me.DataGrid1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
   DataGrid1.Row = DataGrid1.Row + 1
   then i got error

Please tell me if anybody can help me, thank you

Comment: DataGrid is designed to be a bound control.  So without a database or other ADO data source you'd need to create a datasource class.  See "Creating a Data Source" in the VB6 manuals, the topic can't be covered by a simple answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is DataGrid designed to be a bound control, it doesn't support unbound use.  Says so right in the doc.  So, the short answer is that you can't do what you are trying to do, because it's designed to display values from a database.

Instead, you'll want to use the MSFlexGrid control (Not the MSHFlexGrid control, although some of the doc confuses them), which you can read about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228849(v=vs.60).aspx).  Suppose you play around with that (the AddItem method is the fundamental piece you need to work with) and post back with specifics if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the table (DataGrid) right click select edit then you can insert columns:

[image: right click edit]

[image: again right click insert]